# How do I remove "Send to OneNote 2016" from the Windows 10 print dialogue?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, printing, microsoft-onenote

For years I've found it annoying that every time I need to select a printer in Windows 10 that "Send to OneNote 2016" always appears. I don't ever use OneNote, period. How do I get rid of it for good?

Things I have tried:

1. Selecting "Remove Device" from within the windows 10 metro control panel interface > printers and scanners. This works but the printer mysteriously comes back. I haven't tested exactly when this happens, if it is after a restart or at some other time that Microsoft deems fit.
2. Uninstalling OneNote. It doesn't seem to be possible to do this anymore. In the past you would be able to select Microsoft Office in the list of installed programs and select "modify", enabling you to remove unneeded features. This is no longer possible. I even tried running powershell commands to get rid of it (`get-appxpackage *microsoft.office.onenote* | remove-appxpackage`), to no effect.

I am running Microsoft Office 365 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, "Send to Office 2016" is come from OneNote 2016. To remove OneNote 2016 for Office 365, you can use [the Office deployment tool(ODT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-of-the-office-2016-deployment-tool).

The ODT consists of two files: setup.exe and configuration.xml. To work with the tool, you edit the configuration file to define what options you want, and then run setup.exe from the command line as Administrator.

If you are using Office 365 Pro Plus, you can use the follow configuration.xml to remove OneNote 2016:

```
<Configuration>  
 <Add>
      <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
        <ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" />
      </Product>
  </Add>
</Configuration>
```

Then, you need to use configure mode to remove Office products. Example: **setup.exe /configure configuration.xml** . Press Enter to run.

If you are using other versions of Office 365, please modify the value of Product ID according to [the article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/product-ids-that-are-supported-by-the-office-deployment-tool-for-click-to-run-77654e77-aaeb-4ed6-84eb-1d8b0e086590).

[image]

Comment: Microsoft has a online [tool](https://config.office.com/deploymentsettings) that will generate the xml for you.